# Removing characters from a string in Perl that are not alphanumeric

Tags: string, perl, replace

I've used string replacement in Perl a couple of times and have particular substrings and replace them with something else.

I'm curious if there is a trick to only keep certain characters, specifically I want to remove any characters from the string that are not a-z, A-Z or 0-9.

E.g.,   `a b c !@#$%^&*()_~+=[]{}\|;':",./<>? 123`  would just be `abc123`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regex,

```
s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g;
```

using translation,

```
tr/a-zA-Z0-9//dc;
```

Comment: @VenomFangs you can pick any char as separator.

Comment: @VenomFangs: If you want to do a regex *match* then you can omit the `m` as long as you use the default `/` delimiters, so `/abc/` is the same as `m/abc/` and `m~abc~`. Normally you would use a slash unless the pattern itself contained a slash, when `m~a/b~` is clearer than 'm/a\/b/`. A *substitution* always has the leading `s` so you can always use any delimiter you like, but it's worth pointing out that bracket-like characters are paired up so `s/abc/def/` is the same as `s<abc><def>` and `s<b>{x}`.

Comment: Aren't there shortcuts for that, like `\w`? What about Unicode safety?